# How to reuse a selenium driver instance during parallel processing?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, joblib

To scrape a pool of URLs, I am paralell processing selenium with joblib. In this context, I am facing two challenges:

- Challenge 1 is to speed up this process. In the moment, my code opens and closes a driver instance for every URL (ideally would be one for every process)
- Challenge 2 is to get rid of the CPU-intensive while loop that I think I need to `continue` on empty results (I know that this is most likely wrong)

**Pseudocode:**

```
URL_list = [URL1, URL2, URL3, ..., URL100000]                 # List of URLs to be scraped

def scrape(URL):
  while True:                                                 # Loop needed to use continue
          try:                                                # Try scraping
             driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path) # Set up driver
             website = driver.get(URL)                        # Get URL
             results = do_something(website)                  # Get results from URL content                                                
             driver.close()                                   # Close worker
             if len(results) == 0:                            # If do_something() failed:                                                                  
                continue                                      # THEN Worker to skip URL                          
             else:                                            # If do_something() worked:
                safe_results("results.csv")                   # THEN Save results               
                break                                         # Go to next worker/URL
          except Exception as e:                              # If something weird happens:  
                save_exception(URL, e)                        # THEN Save error message
                break                                         # Go to next worker/URL

Parallel(n_jobs = 40)(delayed(scrape)(URL) for URL in URL_list))) # Run in 40 processes
```

My understanding is that in order to re-use a driver instance across iterations, the `# Set up driver`-line needs to be placed outside `scrape(URL)`. However, everything outside `scrape(URL)` will not find its way to joblib's `Parallel(n_jobs = 40)`. This would imply that you can't reuse driver instances while scraping with joblib which can't be true.

**Q1: How to reuse driver instances during parallel processing in the above example?**

**Q2: How to get rid of the while-loop while maintaining functionality in the above-mentioned example?**

*Note: Flash and image loading is disabled in `firefox_profile` (code not shown)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should first create a bunch of drivers: one for each process. And pass an instance to the worker. I don't know how to pass drivers to an Prallel object, but you could use `threading.current_thread().name` key to identify drivers. To do that, use `backend="threading"`. So now each thread will has its own driver.

2) You don't need a loop at all. Parallel object itself iter all your urls (I hope I realy understend your intentions to use a loop)

```
import threading
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from selenium import webdriver

def scrape(URL):
    try:
        driver = drivers[threading.current_thread().name]
    except KeyError:
        drivers[threading.current_thread().name] = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver = drivers[threading.current_thread().name]
    driver.get(URL)
    results = do_something(driver)
    if results:
        safe_results("results.csv")

drivers = {}
Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend="threading")(delayed(scrape)(URL) for URL in URL_list)
for driver in drivers.values():
    driver.quit()
```

But I don't realy think you get profit in using n_job more than you have CPUs. So `n_jobs=-1` is the best (of course I may be wrong, try it).

Comment: looks promising - I just tried it and something creates a memory leak - I will come back to you as soon as i solved this

Comment: @sudonym, what was creating a leak?

Comment: The leak was due to phantomJS (that I now use instead of Firefox) - the 'load_images = no argument' is known to cause this when the phantomJS instance is reused