# Keep browser window open and reuse - Codeception Selenium Chrome Debian

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I'm running Codeception tests. For display purposes, I want to drive the tests on a single Chrome browser [or FF idc], and keep the browser open between test runs. I know there is a way to do this [I did it, but forgot how!].

I'm running:
Ubuntu 20
google-chrome 86

Currently, the tests run fine, and the GUI pops up, but then closes at the end of the run.

I think it has something to do with the parameter "browserSessionReuse" or "restart" or "detach" but I can't figure out where to put it, especially in PHP!

**How can I use just one browser, and keep using it, it Codeception?**

yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - \Helper\Acceptance
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: 'http://xx123xxx.com/'
      port: 4444
      browser: chrome
```

How I launch Selenium:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/WPbdd/chromedriver -jar selenium.jar
```

Comment: Someone has done it in Python, not in PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764902/how-to-reuse-a-selenium-browser-session

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for not answering exatly what you desire, but I think there is no way to do that.

But I suggest you to use codeception console for run one-by-one acceptance test instructions, so this will keep the browser open while you see each command being executed.

And if you use Docker, I suggest you to take a look at this link, for using selenium and Chrome Drive in containers and you may access the interface thru NoVNC (remote desktop access in browser):
https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/hub

Feel free to contact me if you need help with Docker for running that.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Original question was about restart between tests not between test runs.

NEW ANSWER:

Codeception WebDriver module can't do that, but you can implement such functionality yourself.

You would have to create your own module, make it [extend WebDriver](https://github.com/Codeception/module-webdriver/blob/1.1.4/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php), overwrite `_after` and `_afterSuite` method to prevent them from stopping browser instance.
Then implement storing selenium session id to file in `_afterSuite` and update `_initializeSession` method to read session id from file and pass it to constructor of [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/1.9.0/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php#L60-L73) , you will have to copy some core from RemoteWebDriver::create method too.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

That's the default behaviour!
By default WebDriver module reuses the same browser session for all tests and [only deletes cookies between tests](https://github.com/Codeception/module-webdriver/blob/1.1.4/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php#L520-L531).
It is possible to make it restart browser between tests by setting [restart: true](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#Configuration) parameter.

Another way to restart browser is to call [_restart method](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#_restart) in helpers, is there any chance that your Acceptance Helper is executing it?

Comment: I meant keep it open between "test runs" not "tests" I changed it. There is no easy way for Selenium to grab an ALREADY open window. I haven't figured a way to run a test suite multiple times in the same browser. Selenium ALWAYS launches a new session.

Comment: Codeception docs: restart - Set to false (default) to use the same browser window for all tests, or set to true to create a new window for each test. In any case, when all tests are finished the browser window is closed